# embalaje vs envase vs empaque vs envoltorio

Tags: sinónimos

¿Hay alguna diferencia de significado y/o uso entre las palabras "[embalaje](https://dle.rae.es/embalaje?m=form)", "[envase](https://dle.rae.es/envase?m=form)", "[empaque](https://dle.rae.es/empaque?m=form)" y "[envoltorio](https://dle.rae.es/envoltorio?m=form)"? Las definiciones de DLE me parecen muy similares.

¿Podría usar todas esas palabras al referirme a lo que envuelve un champú o un paquete de correo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Las principales diferencias son el tamaño y el tipo de cosa que se envuelve.

- Un **[embalaje](https://dle.rae.es/embalaje?m=form)** es una

> caja o cubierta con la que se resguardan las cosas que han de transportarse.

En mi experiencia, esta palabra se usa para cosas grandes o pesadas. Por ejemplo, un mueble puede venir transportado en un embalaje.

- Un [envase](https://dle.rae.es/envase?m=form) suele contener un líquido, o un sólido en "polvo" o "granos". A fin de cuentas, *envase* está relacionado etimológicamente con *vaso*.
- Un [envoltorio](https://dle.rae.es/envoltorio?m=form) es una

> capa exterior que cubre una cosa

es decir, un envoltorio está "pegado" a aquello que envuelve. Por ejemplo, los caramelos o las magdalenas (muffins) tienen envoltorios. Con esta definición, una caja o paquete no es un envoltorio.

- Nunca he oído ni usado la palabra [empaque](https://dle.rae.es/empaque?m=form), pero según el DLE, un empaque no es un paquete en sí, sino el

> [c]onjunto de materiales que forman la envoltura y armazón de los paquetes

En la página de una [empresa](https://www.envasados.es/diferencias-entre-envase-empaque-y-embalaje/) que se dedica a estas cosas, explican que ellos llaman *envase* a lo que cubre directamente al producto (como una botella de cerveza), *empaque* a un paquete que contiene al envase y cuya función es mayoritariamente estética (como el cartón de un paquete de 6 cervezas) y *embalaje* a las cajas grandes que se usan para almacenar o transportar grandes cantidades de producto (es decir, muchos empaques de 6 cervezas).

De los ejemplos que pones, un champú viene en un *envase* (o *bote*, o quizá *frasco*), y lo que se manda por correo suele ser un *paquete*, o un *embalaje*.

Comment: Para mí el empaque es lo que se pone alrededor de un producto (envoltura y armazón, como dice la def) sobre todo para que no se rompa al ser transportado. No es una palabra muy usada, a menos que uno trabaje de empacador o despachador de productos.